# SSRS Single Multi-value Parameters from Two Columns

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a view I am using in my SSRS report Datasets. I am looking for a solution to have a multi-value parameter to populate values from two separate columns from the view.

This is my view used in my Main Dataset:

[image]

I would like a single multi-value parameter drop down to pull the values from both the EvaluatingSC and the Ongoing SC columns:

This is my StaffRole Dataset for the parameter dropdown:

[image]

My main Dataset to pull the two columns from the view:

[image]

But when I setup the multi-value parameter with the StaffRole Dataset. I have to choose between the two columns:

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to combine both columns in a single multi-value parameter or is my only option to have a two multi-value parameters for each of the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new dataset to supply your parameter's available values list.

Something like

```
SELECT EvaluatingSC AS StaffRole FROM dbo.vStaffRole
UNION
SELECT OnGoingSC FROM dbo.vStaffRole
```

This will give you a single column table with the staff roles in. There is no need to do a `DISTINCT` as `UNION` does this by default.